# `curl --version` doesn't show latest version just downloaded

Tags: macos, curl

Mac 10.8.5

I thought I'd downloaded and installed the latest version of curl (7.44.0) like so:

1. Downloaded the latest source archive (.tar.gz)
2. Put it into a new folder on my desktop and `cd`'d to that folder
3. Expanded the tar file: `tar -xvf curl-7.44.0.tar` then `cd`'d into the newly created "curl-7.44.0" subdirectory
4. Did `./configure`, `make`, `make test` (99% success rate), and `sudo make install`

I see that there are indeed header files in /Usr/local/include/curl and the libraries are at /Usr/local/lib/libcurl.a and /Usr/local/lib/libcurl.dylib .

Yet when I run `curl --version` it spits out 7.24.0 (the version that came with my computer):

```
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
```

What still needs to be done, or what's the proper, easiest way to update curl on a Mac?

**Edit:** What's the proper way to check the current version of curl installed?

Comment: try: ./curl --version

Comment: "no such file or directory"..

Comment: use brew to install it.

Comment: `Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.41.0: 301 files, 3.0M`, but `curl --version` still returns 7.24.0

Comment: Try `curl -V` to check the version